Spark Arbitrary Stateful Operations - how does Spark manage the timeout?
I'm looking at this example and also tried to apply it for my use case, but I couldn't understand how Spark uses the hasTimedOut to manage the data in memory. For example, what happen if I handle a session by its key and stop receiving events for this specific key - that's mean I'm no longer going to get into the mergeSessions function for this key, and consequently never will evict the events that related to this key so they will remain in the memory.
Am I wrong? I would love to get some explanation about that - how should I manage the eviction of sessions that I stopped receiving events for?
